# Circuit to enable/disable ESP32 GPIO pins during bootstrap

Tags: gpio, esp32

I am developing an ESP32 board and I need to use all the GPIO pins of the ESP32. But I have some problems during bootstrap, since:

- some GPIOs emit a PWM signal which can affect the connected circuits;
- some GPIOs cannot be pulled high / low otherwise boot fails.

I need a circuit to disable these pins during bootstrap and to enable them during code execution. This circuit should be controlled by a high/low signal from one of the "bootstrap-safe" pins of the ESP32.
What circuit should I use? Can anyone give me an example schematic?

Comment: I don't put this as an answer as you arw basically asking what to buy which is off-topic, and it also depends on what the things are you need to control, but have you looked at three-state buffers?

Comment: usually you match up the pin with the task. Like connecting an oft-used button to GPIO0 or an LED to one of the pins with PWM upon boot; make the side-effects harmless. If you need full specific arbitrary control of every GPIO, the ESP32 is not a good match for your project.